# Selected Menu Link In Wordpress Custom Theme Does Not Work

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I'm developing a custom Wordpress theme and I have got a problem with a selected menu link in my theme!

Basically I have added a class name to my CSS file which is called `selected`. It shows how to the current page gonna be displayed in the top menu navigation.

This is the CSS file:

```
.ddsmoothmenu{
    float: right;
    margin-top: 10px
}

.ddsmoothmenu ul{
    z-index:100;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}

/*Top level list items*/
.ddsmoothmenu ul li{
    position: relative;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
}

/*Top level menu link items style*/
.ddsmoothmenu ul li a{
    display: block;
    height: 26px;
    line-height: 23px;
    padding: 0 20px 5px 15px;
    margin: 0 7px 0 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #333;    
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 700;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
}

* html .ddsmoothmenu ul li a{ /*IE6 hack to get sub menu links to behave correctly*/
display: inline-block;
}

.ddsmoothmenu ul li a.selected, .ddsmoothmenu ul li a:hover { /*CSS class that's dynamically added to the currently active menu items' LI A element*/
    position: relative;
    background: url(../images/templatemo_mhr.png) no-repeat top right;
}

.ddsmoothmenu ul li a.selected span, .ddsmoothmenu ul li a:hover span {
    position: absolute;
    width: 5px;
    height: 26px;
    top: 0;
    left: -5px;
    background: url(../images/templatemo_mhl.png) no-repeat;
}

/*1st sub level menu*/
.ddsmoothmenu ul li ul{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    display: none; /*collapse all sub menus to begin with*/
    visibility: hidden;
    background: #bad8f7;
}

/*Sub level menu list items (undo style from Top level List Items)*/
.ddsmoothmenu ul li ul li{
display: list-item;
float: none;
}

/*All subsequent sub menu levels vertical offset after 1st level sub menu */
.ddsmoothmenu ul li ul li ul{
top: 0;
}

/* Sub level menu links style */
.ddsmoothmenu ul li ul li a{
    font-weight: 500;
    width: 120px; /*width of sub menus*/
    padding: 2px 10px;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 12px;
    border-top-width: 0;
    text-align: left;
}


.ddsmoothmenu ul li ul li a.selected, .ddsmoothmenu ul li ul li a:hover { text-decoration: underline; background: none }

/* Holly Hack for IE \*/
* html .ddsmoothmenu{height: 1%;} /*Holly Hack for IE7 and below*/


/* ######### CSS classes applied to down and right arrow images  ######### */

.downarrowclass{
position: absolute;
top: 12px;
right: 7px;
}

.rightarrowclass{
position: absolute;
top: 6px;
right: 5px;
}

/* ######### CSS for shadow added to sub menus  ######### */

.ddshadow{
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 0;
width: 0;
height: 0;
background: #fff;
}

.toplevelshadow{ /*shadow opacity. Doesn't work in IE*/
opacity: 0.5;
}

/* menu */
```

And here's the menu layout in `header.php` file:

```
<div id="templatemo_header">
        <div id="site_title"><h1><a href="#">Violet Theme</a></h1></div>
        <div id="templatemo_menu" class="ddsmoothmenu">
            <?php 
            $args = array(
                'theme_location' => 'primary'
            );
            wp_nav_menu($args); 
            ?>
            <br style="clear: left" />
        </div> <!-- end of templatemo_menu -->

        <div class="cleaner"></div>
    </div> <!-- end of templatemo header -->
```

How to add the class `selected` to the current menu page so if a user clicked on *blog*  page for example ,the *blog* item changed to the selected item's style in the menu...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `current-menu-item`, because ti will be added to the page/posts/category that you are currently viewing. It's not recommended to use `current_page_item` because it will be added only if the menu item is a page.

Answer (score 0):

In wordpress you will have class `current_page_item` when you seleted menu. You can set color of `<a>` at here

```
.current_page_item a{color: #xxxxxx;}
```

And if you want to set color when hover

```
.category a:hover{color: #xxxxxx;}
```